# Vize.ai Image Recognition in iOS app

Tags: ios, image, request, swift4, image-recognition

I am trying to implement the [Vize.ai](http://vize.ai) image recognition in an iOS app using Swift 4.

In their [documentation](https://vize.ai/docs) this is the code example they give for Objective C:

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Authorization": @"JWT {your JWT token}", @"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", @"Accept": @"text/plain"};
UNIUrlConnection *asyncConnection = [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
  [request setUrl:@"http://cl-api.vize.ai/{your task ID}?image={path/myimage.png}"];
  [request setHeaders:headers];
}] asundefinedAsync:^(UNIHTTPundefinedResponse *response, NSError *error) {
  NSInteger code = response.code;
  NSDictionary *responseHeaders = response.headers;
  UNIJsonNode *body = response.body;
  NSData *rawBody = response.rawBody;
}];
```

As you can see I have to pass an image path to the request. In my app the user can either chose to analyse a default picture that is added to the project's assets folder or add from library/take a photo.

What is that image Path supposed to be in this example?

Here is how I am making the request with Swift 4, any image path I am adding to it it gives me an "missing image or url" response error back:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "JWT \(jwtToken)",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "text/plain"
]
let url = "https://cl-api.vize.ai/\(taskID)?image=\(imagePath)"
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to find a solution for this using multipart form data. Here is the complete code for it.

```
func getVizeImageAnalysis(image: UIImage) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "JWT \(jwtToken)",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "text/plain"
        ]
        let url = "https://cl-api.vize.ai/\(taskID)"

        manager.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPartData in
            // Add image
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)  {
                multiPartData.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "pickedImage", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }

        }, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let request, _, _):
                request.responseJSON{ response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Alamofire? If you are, I'm getting a `Use of unresolved identifier error`on `HTTPHeaders` and `manager`. Do you know what the problem might be? I've already installed Alamofire using CocoaPods.

Comment: Also, jwtToken is the API access token, and taskID is the Task UIUD, correct? When I enter fill in those placeholders with my own API token and task ID, I'm getting this error: `Expected a digit after integer literal prefix`. Did you encounter this as well?

Comment: @fi12 yes I am using Alamofire, make sure to initialise the manager: `class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    let manager: SessionManager

(...)

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let sessionConfiguration = SessionManager.default.session.configuration
        sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0
        self.manager = SessionManager(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

(...)

}`

Comment: @fi12 Yes the jwtToken is the API access token and the taskID is task UUID. Are you adding them as Strings?